# Yii2 - How to remove blank space from Gridview Filter

Tags: yii2

I have this gridview

[image: GridviewFilter]

I want to replace the blank space on the status with **All**, so that it will have **All, Active, Inactive**

**View:Gridview**

```
            [
            'class' => '\pheme\grid\ToggleColumn',
            'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'text-center'],
            'attribute'=>'is_status',
            'enableAjax' => false,
            'filter'=>['1'=>'InActive', '0'=>'Active'],
        ],
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Try to add one more option like `'filter'=>['' => All, '1'=>'InActive', '0'=>'Active'],`

Comment: I did that, but the blank space is still there. I don't want the blank space there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [filterInputOptions](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn#$filterInputOptions-detail)

```
[
   'class' => '\pheme\grid\ToggleColumn',
   'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'text-center'],
   'attribute' => 'is_status',
   'enableAjax' => false,
   'filter' => ['1' => 'InActive', '0' => 'Active'],
   'filterInputOptions' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => null, 'prompt' => 'All'],
],
```